# image description using sticky position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create an image with a description. The idea is that the image and the description are flexed, and aligned center, and the description will be hidden initially. When the user scrolls through the image, the description will become visible. All this I want able to achieve through javascript. The problem is, when the description becomes visible, I want it to trail until the end of the image. I used sticky position for this but there was no success. Can anyone tell me how to get the desired style? I am attaching part of my code for reference.

```js
const hiddenText = document.getElementById('hiddenText');

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
  const story3 = document.querySelector('.story3');
  const story3Top = story3.getBoundingClientRect().top;

  if (story3Top < windowHeight / 4) {
    hiddenText.style.opacity = 1;
  } else {
    hiddenText.style.opacity = 0;
  }
});
```

```css
  .container {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  /* Enable vertical scrolling for the container */
}

.story3 {
  position: relative;
  top: 40rem;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 100%;
}

#hiddenText {
  font-size: 2rem;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.story3 img {
  width: 500px;
  height: 670px;
  position: relative;
}

.scroll {
  position: relative;
  top: 100rem;
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="story3">
    <div class="container">
      <p id="hiddenText">Unleash new territories</p>
    </div>
    <img src="https://pixabay.com/photos/sea-ocean-coast-nature-boat-3352341/" alt="">
  </div>
  <div style="height: 100px;"></div>
</div>

<div class="scroll">
  <a href="">x2</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You put the stickiness on the wrong thing. Simple fix: Put it on the `.container` class instead of `#hiddenText`. The container holding the text is what needs to stick to the top of `.story3`, *not* the text itself.

```
.container {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  /* Enable vertical scrolling for the container */
}

/* ... */

#hiddenText {
  font-size: 2rem;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

/* ... */
```